# Inertial Scrolling on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css

I did a parallax site http://skinnibones.herokuapp.com/ using Keith Clark's pure css parallax scrolling tutorial. So far it's the best parallax effect since it used only css.

But it has problem on ios, it lost its inertial scrolling or some call it momentum scrolling.

I tried

```
overflow-y: scroll;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
```

but no luck.

Comment: could you reproduce this in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or snippet so that we could see for ourselves? Please kindly note that links to personal sites are discouraged as this question will loose its integrity if the link is broken or updated

Comment: @jbutler483 the css http://jsfiddle.net/href64e3/